# a site stopped working after some days and gives me a weak connection when I scrape it by scrapy and I cannot scrape data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this site https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13140131-dvorska-bouda-restaurace-strazne.html

Five days ago, I scraped this site and it worked normally. Now when I try to scrape it, it gives me no data. When I open it on my browser, I can see the result and open the page without error. Also when I scrape this site from the shell it works normally.

#### My code:

```
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy,time,os,re
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

try:

    class FirmySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'firmy'
        start_urls = ['https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13140131-dvorska-bouda-restaurace-strazne.html']


        def parse(self, response):
            open_in_browser(response)
            address=''
            social=''
            email=''
            phone = ''

            subcategories=''
            name=response.css('#box4 .print::text').get()#name
            if name==None:
                name = response.css('.header::text').get( ) # name
            if name==None:
                name = response.css('h1::text').get( ) # name
            if name==None:
                name=''
            for item in response.css('.sAddress > div::text').getall():
                address+=item
            website_url=response.css('.mainUrl .companyUrl::text').get()#web
            for p in response.css('.info span::text').getall():#phone number
                phone += f'{p}-------'

            for item in response.css('a.socialUrl::attr(href)').getall() : #social
                social+=f'{item}-------'

            for item in response.css('.companyMail::text').getall():#email
                email+=item

            description=response.css('#box5 .description::text').get( ) # description
            if description==None:
                description=''
            for item in  response.css('#box16 a::text').getall(): #subcategories
                subcategories+=f'{item}-------'
            subcategories = subcategories[:-7]
            social = social[:-7]
            phone = phone[:-7]
            subcategories = subcategories[:-7]
            item={
                'listing url':response.url,
                'Name':name.replace(',', '').replace('\t','').replace('\n','').encode('utf-8').decode('latin2'),
                'address':address.replace(',', '').replace('\n','').encode('utf-8').decode('latin2'),
                'website url':website_url,
                'phone numbers':phone.replace(',', ''),
                'social media profiles':social.replace(',', '').replace('\n',''),
                ' e-mail address': email.replace(',', ''),
                'description ':description.replace(',', '').replace(';', '').replace('\n','').encode('utf-8').decode('latin2'),
                'Kategorie': subcategories.replace(',', '').replace('\n','').encode('utf-8').decode('latin2')


            }
            yield item
    if __name__ == "__main__":
            #make folder
            try:
                os.mkdir('results folder')
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
            try:
                os.remove(f"results folder/{FirmySpider.name} data.csv")
            except:
                pass
           
            DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES={
            #'utf_32'
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
            'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING':'utf_8',
                'PROXY_POOL_ENABLED': True,
                'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,

                'FEED_URI': f'results folder/{FirmySpider.name} data.csv',
            # 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': .5,
            # 'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True,
            # 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',

            }
            process = CrawlerProcess(DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES)
            process.crawl(FirmySpider)
            process.start()
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error   {e}')
    time.sleep(10)
else:
    print(f'Finshed')
    # time.sleep(10)
```

#### Result

```
C:\Users\ahmed\PycharmProjects\exe_conventer_for_webscraping\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ahmed/PycharmProjects/exe_conventer_for_webscraping/firmy.py
2021-05-20 23:07:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2021-05-20 23:07:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), cryptography 3.4.7, Platform Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
2021-05-20 23:07:16 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf_8', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'results folder/firmy data.csv', 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408], 'RETRY_TIMES': 10}
2021-05-20 23:07:17 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: f1dc58a95537ff11
2021-05-20 23:07:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-05-20 23:07:21 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-05-20 23:07:21 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-05-20 23:07:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-05-20 23:07:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-05-20 23:07:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-05-20 23:07:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2021-05-20 23:07:22 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Proxy user pass not found
2021-05-20 23:07:22 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Using proxy <http://190.131.247.30:4153>, 183 proxies left
2021-05-20 23:07:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13140131-dvorska-bouda-restaurace-strazne.html> (referer: None)
2021-05-20 23:07:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13140131-dvorska-bouda-restaurace-strazne.html>
{'listing url': 'https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13140131-dvorska-bouda-restaurace-strazne.html', 'Name': '', 'address': '', 'website url': None, 'phone numbers': '', 'social media profiles': '', ' e-mail address': '', 'description ': '', 'Kategorie': ''}
2021-05-20 23:07:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-05-20 23:07:25 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (1 items) in: results folder/firmy data.csv
2021-05-20 23:07:25 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 264,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5979,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.823218,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 20, 20, 7, 25, 926400),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 20, 20, 7, 22, 103182)}
2021-05-20 23:07:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
Finshed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

when I open result on the browser by `open_in_browser`

[image: see img]

I tried:

1. use user agent
2. use proxy

Comment: Were you scraping them over and over and over?  It's possible their router detected you as am abuser and has blocked you.

Comment: thank you for response

Comment: I found solution

Answer (score 0):

I found solution
I tried this script on python ide and it works without error
I do not know why and how it works on ide and not works on pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the `scrapy-proxies` using 10 IP's from https://free-proxy-list.net/

scrapy-proxies: https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies